# Python create dataframe from multiple dataframes with one having multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 NumPy dataframes, which I want to merge with Pandas to a DataFrame in order to some actions.

My dataframes are:

dataframe1, size (38 x 9)

```
at1 at2 at3 at4 at5 at6 at7 at8 at9
43  -0.333333   91.3333 -4  31.3333 -1.33333    48.6667 59.6667 11.3333
54.5    4   79  0   12  5.5 24  67  43
40.4    0.4 85.6    0.2 31.6    1.6 45  53.4    8.8
```

dataframe2, size (38 x 1)

```
at10
43
25
2
```

dataframe3, size (38 x 1)

```
at1
-3
5
20
```

My code so far is the following:

```
df = DataFrame (
            {"reps": array1,
            "labels": array2,
            "weight": array3}
            )
```

When I execute this, I receive the following error message:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

I've spent a lot of time trying things, with no luck.
Any idea?

Comment: Your `np.arrays` don't look like arrays. Rather they look like dataframes.

Comment: Did you mean that you have 3 Pandas dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the error, array 1 which is a multidimensional array is manipulated so as to get each array, this is done by converting it to a list.

Then a dictionary with all array values is created to make the solution elegant.

```py
import pandas as pd

# get number of columns in multidimensional array 
num_cols = len(array1)

# create column names
array1_col_names = ['reps_' + str(i) for i in range(num_cols)]

# get elements of array 1 and store them in a dictionary
values = dict(zip(col_names, list(array1)))
values.update({'labels': array2, 'weight': array3}) # add other arrays to dictionary

# create dataframe from the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(values)

df
```

Comment: Almost correct, expect the fact that I have to transpose the other 2 arrays, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have updated the solution so that you won't have to transpose the arrays. It is more elegant also.

Answer (score 0):

You can covert each np(Numpy) array to pd (Pandas) Dataframe and then concat using pd.concat

```
at1=[43,54.5,40.4]
at2=[-0.33333,4,0.4]
at3=[91.3333,79,85.6]
at4=[-4,0,0.2]
at5=[31.3333,12,31.6]
at6=[1.33333,5.5,1.6]
at7=[48.6667,24,45]
at8=[59.6667,67,53.4]
at9=[11.3333,43,8.8]

base_at=np.array([at1,at2,at3,at4,at5,at6,at7,at8,at9])
```

This is your array1

```
at10=np.array([43,25,2])
at11=np.array([-3,5,20])
```

These are your array2 and array3 respectively.

```
at10_df=pd.DataFrame(at10).T
base_at_df=pd.DataFrame(base_at)
at11_df=pd.DataFrame(at11).T
```

You converted all three arrays into respective DataFrames

```
pd.concat([base_at_df,at10_df,at11_df])
```

And this is your DataFrame comprising of all three arrays

Here's the solution, I haven't changed the name of column, I think you can handle from here.